# Python lexicographic string ordering on unicode strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

Python's string ordering is rather straightforward for ascii strings, `'b' > 'a'`, and `'aa' > 'a'`, as by lexicographic ordering. But what happens when the strings are in unicode?

I would expect greater than to have the following behavior:

```
def greater_than(s1, s2):
    return tuple(map(ord, s1)) > tuple(map(ord, s2))
```

i.e. we compare each ordinal in lexicographic order. Is this what python does?

The [utf-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) encoding encodes the first byte of a character depending on the number of bytes in the sequence, in increasing order, therefore if strings were utf-8 encoded, a byte compare would do the job. I'm also wondering if compares are implemented this way.

Comment: I think this is done in `PyUnicode_Compare`, haven't been able to find it's source yet.

Answer (score 0):

`PyUnicode_Compare` is defined here: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/unicodeobject.c

It calls `unicode_compare`, a static function.  You can see that there are two versions: one using a table of "fixups" to deal with values which cannot be compared directly as numbers, and one naive implementation.  The "smarter" implementation is hidden by `#if 0` currently, suggesting that Python is simply comparing the ordinal values:

```
while (len1 > 0 && len2 > 0) {
    Py_UNICODE c1, c2;

    c1 = *s1++;
    c2 = *s2++;

    if (c1 != c2)
        return (c1 < c2) ? -1 : 1;

    len1--; len2--;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the svn repo a bit dated? Looks rather different to the [github version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c) updated 2 days ago. Just wondering whether it's changed since then (hopefully not).

Comment: @simonzack: Indeed.  I just took the first one I found in Google.